# REST - Addressability of resources (Composition, Collection)

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I'm designing a `REST-API` and currently I'm stuck with the following question. For example I got the following structure:

```
/foods/fruits/{fruit}
/foods/meat/{meat}
```

for example:

```
/foods/fruits/apple
/foods/fruits/pineapple
/foods/meat/chicken
```

Each of the endpoints is unique (`only one apple, one chicken`), but different sorts of `fruits` can exist (e.g. pineapple). 
However my `service` needs to return either

- one specific fruit (apple),
- all fruits (collection-resource filled with all accessible fruits --> apple, pineapple)
- or the whole food (composition of the collection-resources of fruits and meat)

With this design my resource is addressable about 3 `URIs` (`composition, collection, endpoint`), but it should be a maxima of 2.
It this a restful design?

Comment: Nobody got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this design my ressource is addressable about 3 URIs (composition, collection, endpoint), but it should be a maxima of 2. It this a restful design?

Could you provide a reference for the guideline that it should be a maxima of 2?

But either way - those three URIs are not 3 different URIs for the same resource, they are three different resources:

1. the food resource
2. a collection of foods of a particular type
3. a particular type of food

While the earlier resources can be considered to be composed of the others, it does not mean that the finest grain (the particular type, e.g. apple) is addressable via 3 URIs.

If you are using a hypermedia format such as [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) your composition representation could utilised *embedded* resources, which clearly illustrates that the contained resources are also available directly via their own endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), you could have a generic `Food` resource and endpoint, with properties like type and name, and then your requirements would be accessible like so:

- `GET /api/food?name=apple`
- `GET /api/food?type=fruit`
- `GET /api/food`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thinks this may help.